# jQuery parent selector not working with two groups of divs

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have the following case where I want to find the 4th parent who has an especific width value, and having that modify the font-size a child, like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class='parent4-a'>
  <div class='parent3'>
    <div class='parent2'>
      <div class='parent1'>
        <div class='parent0'>
          <div class='child'>
            <p>Hello World?</p>
          </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent4-a{  
  width:600px;
}

.child{
  background-color:grey;
  width:100%;
}
p{
  font-size:15px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  if($('.child').parents().eq(4).css('width') >='595px'){
  $('.child p').css({'font-size':'25px'})  
}
});
```

it can be seen it in this pen: https://codepen.io/jotasMAJA/pen/ZEJmXdd

But, when I've tried to implement the same behaviour having another group of divs, changing the class name of the 5th parent the jQuery code doesn't work?

like this:

**HTML** Adding the same but having two 5th parent, parent4-a and parent4-b:

```
<div class='parent4-a'>
  <div class='parent3'>
    <div class='parent2'>
      <div class='parent1'>
        <div class='parent0'>
          <div class='child'>
            <p>Hello World?</p>
          </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='parent4-b'>
  <div class='parent3'>
    <div class='parent2'>
      <div class='parent1'>
        <div class='parent0'>
          <div class='child'>
            <p>Hello World?</p>
          </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS** Defining now different width sizes, being at both sides of the jQuery condition:

```
.parent4-b{  
  width:300px;
}
.parent4-a{  
  width:600px;
}

.child{
  background-color:grey;
  width:100%;
}
p{
  font-size:15px;
}
```

**jQuery remains the same**

you can see it in this pen: https://codepen.io/jotasMAJA/pen/xxLmxLE

and this is my question:

What must be done to have change the font size of the p tag related with the width in the 5th parent?

Why does the jQuery code work only for one single group of divs?

Comment: `Why the jQuery code works only for one single group of divs?` I think because you use a class and jQuery select the last group, so ti works only here.

Comment: And `console.log($('.child').parents().eq(4).css('width'));` returns 300px

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple `.child` elements so you have to loop trouch every `.child` element.

You can use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method of jquery.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.child').each(function( index ) {
     if($(this).parents().eq(4).css('width') >='595px'){
        $('p', this).css({'font-size':'25px'})  
      }
  });
  
});
```

```css
.parent4-b{  
  width:300px;
}
.parent4-a{  
  width:600px;
}

.child{
  background-color:grey;
  width:100%;
}
p{
  font-size:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent4-a'>
  <div class='parent3'>
    <div class='parent2'>
      <div class='parent1'>
        <div class='parent0'>
          <div class='child'>
            <p>Hello World?</p>
          </div>
         </div>
       </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class='parent4-b'>
  <div class='parent3'>
    <div class='parent2'>
      <div class='parent1'>
        <div class='parent0'>
          <div class='child'>
            <p>Hello World?</p>
          </div>
         </div>
       </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Careful here: `$('.child p').css({'font-size':'25px'})`, it's applying that to all `.child p`. It should be either `$(this).find('p')` or `$('p', this)` to apply only to the width condition.

Comment: ups, it's right, updated the answer.

Comment: okok, nevertheless in the real use case is going to be #child p, so, I think will be unique

Comment: You can't have more than one id

Comment: true...in my real use case is about the same #child be called twice with diferents parents

Comment: uh oh, very important $(this).find('p') or $('p', this).

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through each `.child` to get it to work.
Here's an example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.child').each(function() {
    if($(this).parents().eq(4).css('width') >='595px') {
      $('p', this).css({'font-size':'25px'})  
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call .eq() it starts counting the fist element with 1 (not starting with 0 like an Array). So if you want the 5th parent you actually have to call .eq(5) on the parents:

```
if ($(".child").parents().eq(5).css("width") >= "595px") {
  $(".child p").css({ "font-size": "25px" });
}
```

Comment: The jquery snippet that goes in my first example works fine.proving that with eq(4) get the job done, the issue was that needed to go over all the child elements (when is more that one) and after that change the property of the elements that meet the condition, all the answers were done here correctly, you can check the pens related